# Dynamic query Paramters Apache Drill.: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Prepared-statement dynamic parameters are not supported

Tags: java, hdfs, apache-drill

How do I set Dynamic query parameters in Apache drill. I tried and received error message saying: `java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException`:

> Prepared-statement dynamic parameters are not supported.

Is it true that drill does not support such a feature, as in:

```
String sql = "select employee_id,first_name,last_name from dfs.'employee.json' where id = ?";
PreparedStatement preparedStatement =   conn.prepareStatement(sql);
preparedStatement.setString(1, 23);
ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery(sql);
```

Can any one please suggest a work around for this, if there's any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now, this support is not there. Drill does not support Prepared-statement dynamic parameters.If still some one wants to go ahead with such dynamic parametres for their queries, they would have to set using statements this way:

```
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
    String queryParam = "Computers"
    String sqlQuery = "select employee_id,first_name,last_name from dfs.'employee.json' where department LIKE'" +queryParam +"'"+"and conditions<...> ";
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sqlQuery);
                while(rs.next)
               {
                 do as you need
                }
```